# UIGraphicsContext memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, uigraphicscontext

Hi In my app I have a function that takes an Image of the current view and turns it into a blurred image then adds it to the current.view. All though I remove the view using [remove from superview] it the memory still stays high. I am using core graphics and set all of the UI Images to zero.

I do get a memory leak warning[image]

```
-(void)burImage
{
    //Get a screen capture from the current view.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 450));
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Blur the image
    CIImage *blurImg = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImg.CGImage];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
    [clampFilter setValue:blurImg forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [clampFilter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];

    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:clampFilter.outputImage forKey: @"inputImage"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:22.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImg = [context createCGImage:gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage fromRect:[blurImg extent]];
    UIImage *outputImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];

    //Add UIImageView to current view.
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 450)];
    [imgView setTag:1109];

    imgView.image = outputImg;
    [imgView setTag:1108];

    gaussianBlurFilter = nil;
    outputImg = nil;
    blurImg = nil;

    viewImg = nil;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Is your project using ARC ?

Comment: BTW, I think you have an extra `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` at the end of your method. I don't know if that extra call has deleterious effects, but you should probably remove that.

Comment: Also, I don't understand your intent of calling `setTag` twice is (as the second one only overrides the value of the first one). And you didn't answer subj singh's important question: It's important because if not using ARC, you are probably leaking your `UIImageView`, too.

Comment: the setTag twice was a mistake. I used that to easily remove the view from the root view.

Answer (score 1):

The static analyzer ("Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu) is informing you that you are missing a needed `CGImageRelease(cgImg)` at the end of your method. If you have a Core foundation object returned from a method/function with "Create" or "Copy" in the name, you are responsible for releasing it.

By the way, if you tap on the [image] icon (once in the margin, and again on the version that appears in the error message), it will show you more information:

[image]

That can be helpful for tracking back to where the problem originated, in this case the call to `createCGImage`. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001310-BCIFIFEE) for `createCGImage`, it confirms this diagnosis, reporting:

> **Return Value**
>
> A Quartz 2D image. You are responsible for releasing the returned image when you no longer need it.

For general counsel about releasing Core Foundation objects, see the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) in the *Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation.*

Comment: Thanks Rob I had added the CGImageRelease(cgImg) but it still racks up memory every time its called. I will check out the Create Rule thanks

Comment: Yes I am using ARC. The memory leak is now gone from Analyzer. I have removed the second EndImageContext. I have ran the code in parts and as soon as it hits CGImageRef cgImg = [context createCGImage:gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage fromRect:[blurImg extent]]; it jumps up 15mb but after adding it I release using CGImageRelease(cgImg)

Comment: What is extremely annoying is I have stepped through the code and the memory goes up as soon as I assign an image ref even though I try to release immediately it stays the same.

Comment: CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImg = [context createCGImage:gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage fromRect:[blurImg extent]];
    CGImageRelease(cgImg); // this was just to check if it would release the memory

Comment: @Mike We've solved the problem in your code with my answer. We're now trying to track down some secondary source of leak, so we should [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38513/discussion-between-rob-and-mike).